# poller process in activiti

Tags: java, activiti

I have created an activiti process for the lifecycle of an email which passes many service tasks.

Now I have another process that polls emails from a queue and starts the new activiti email process everytime a new email is polled.
the poller process should never stop polling.

I understand that an activiti process(the poller) is not meant to never end?
I tried to make this work, but when an error occurs in 1 of my activiti email processes, the poller process also stops.

How should this be made?
I am thinking about the REST API?
(I create my poller outside of activiti, and I call the api everytime a new email process needs to be started?)

I really want to keep everything within my activiti explorer, but is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the timer for the polling process. such tat polling can happen at periodic intervals.

Do check about Activiti timer events. The timer can also be added at the process level, its not just for tasks.

Comment: Is it possible to start multiple email processes(without ending sequential) from 1 timer process?

Comment: so the email processes can start asynchronically